# Flutter Pixel 7 SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, pixel

Good afternoon and thank you in advance. I'm starting a project in Flutter, Pixel 6, with Api 33 it works great, but in Api 33 it doesn't read the file created with Shared properly.... if I query data, it finds, it shows "YES". instead, it does not show the value of the variable. Any ideas?

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();    
if(prefs.containsKey("user")){
          String? value = prefs.getString('user');
          print("CCCCCCCCCCCCC  "+value!);
          print("YES");
        }else{
          print ("no");
        }
```

I have tried several options and it doesn't work